# c++ vector of non-pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, smart-pointers

I have a `TileMap` class that has a `std::vector<Tile>`. While just generating the vector, i notice that the `Tile`s are getting deleted shortly after creation, thus not letting the `TileMap` class do anything with them.

`TileMap` is a kind of information class that will be used by a `Stage` class for various things, so it will need to access `TileMap.tiles()` (which returns the `mTiles_` `TileMap`.

TileMap constructor:

```
TileMap::TileMap(std::vector<int> pTiles, int pWidth):mWidth_(pWidth)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < pTiles.size(); i++)
    {
        int x = (i % mWidth_);
        int y = floorf(i / mWidth_);
        Tile tile((Tile::TileType)pTiles[i]);
        tile.x = x;
        tile.y = y;
        tile.position(sf::Vector2f(x * Tile::TILE_WIDTH, y * Tile::TILE_HEIGHT));
        mTiles_.push_back(tile);
    }
}
```

Previously it was a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tile>>` but i was seeing if i could get around using pointers. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: Tile definition added -

```
class Tile : public SquareCollidableObject
{
public:

    enum TileType {
        TILE_GRASS,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_TOP_LEFT_OUTER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_TOP,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_TOP_RIGHT_OUTER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_LEFT,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_RIGHT,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_RIGHT_INNER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_LEFT_INNER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_LEFT_OUTER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_TOP_RIGHT_INNER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_TOP_LEFT_INNER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_RIGHT_OUTER,
        TILE_WALL,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_TOP_LEFT_INNER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_TOP,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_TOP_RIGHT_INNER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_LEFT,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_RIGHT,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_RIGHT_OUTER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_LEFT_OUTER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_LEFT_INNER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_TOP_RIGHT_OUTER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_TOP_LEFT_OUTER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_RIGHT_INNER,
        TILE_FLOOR
    };

    Tile(TileType);
    virtual ~Tile();

    virtual void update(float);
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderWindow&, sf::Vector2f);

    TileType tileType;

    static int TILE_WIDTH;
    static int TILE_HEIGHT;

    int x;
    int y;

    // pathfinding
    std::shared_ptr<Tile> previousTile;
    float g; // cost to tile (total cost from previous tiles + cost to this tile)
    float h; // cost to next tile
    float f; // g + h
    bool walkable;
};
```

Comment: `tile` is a local variable in the `for` loop. Each iteration creates a new one, which is destroyed when that iteration ends.

Comment: Which is fine (or should be fine), since he is pushing a copy of `tile` into the vector. If it's *not* fine, then that probably indicates that the `Tile` class does not implement proper value semantics.

Comment: Please show the definition of the class `Tile`. From the `TileMap` constructor code, `Tile` looks like a class where the default copy-constructor should suffice, but it would help to see what you have.

Comment: [OT]:Your `floorf` is useless, as integer division already does that thing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a full working example of your code and it's usage rather than a few snippets. If you don't want to share all your code, try reducing it down to a snippet which demonstrates your problem in it's entirety.

Answer (score 1):

`Tile` needs to have a copy (or move) constructor and assignment operator for use with `std::vector`.
`nTiles_.push_back(tile)` copy-constructs a new `Tile` object from the local `tile`.

In that for loop, at each iteration, the local object `tile` gets constructed, then a copy gets pushed into the vector, and then the local `tile` gets destructed. This is why destructors get called during the for loop.

One way to avoid this and instead only construct the `Tile` object that will be in the `vector`, you could write

```
TileMap::TileMap(std::vector<int> pTiles, int pWidth):mWidth_(pWidth)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < pTiles.size(); i++)
    {
        int x = (i % mWidth_);
        int y = floorf(i / mWidth_);

        mTiles_.emplace_back( (Tile::TileType)pTiles[i] );
        Tile& tile = mTiles_.back();
        tile.x = x;
        tile.y = y;
        tile.position(sf::Vector2f(x * Tile::TILE_WIDTH, y * Tile::TILE_HEIGHT));
    }
}
```

`emplace_back` takes the arguments of the `Tile` constructor, and constructs an object in-place at the end of the `vector`. `back` returns a reference to the last item.

If `Tile` objects are heavy-weight (i.e. copying them is expensive), it may be better to use pointers instead as before, or implement move-constructor and move-assignment operator. `std::vector` will copy (or move) its items if new items get inserted/erased, or when the vector gets resized.

Also the `tiles()` function needs to return the `vector` by reference.

Comment: I tried this and i still see that the tiles are being deleted, in a really strange fashion. I'll look into it more, but would the `Tile& tile = mTiles_.back();` create a tile and then call its destructor at the end of the loop?

Comment: If i remove the reference it still calls the destrcutor for these tiles.

Comment: I've tried this (see my answer) and @tmlen's answer looks like it works to me. When exactly are you seeing the destructor being called?

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 reasons of Tile destruction in your code:

The local variable that you copy inside vector, and the internal copy when vector resizes internal memory.

To avoid the former, you have to emplace back the new element; for the later, you have to reserve place in vector. It results in something like:

```
TileMap::TileMap(const std::vector<int>& pTiles, int pWidth) : mWidth_(pWidth)
{
    mTiles_.reserve(pTiles.size());
    for(int i = 0; i != pTiles.size(); ++i)
    {
        const int x = i % mWidth_;
        const int y = i / mWidth_;
        mTiles_.emplace_back(static_cast<Tile::TileType>(pTiles[i]));
        Tile& tile = mTiles_.back();
        tile.x = x;
        tile.y = y;
        tile.position(sf::Vector2f(x * Tile::TILE_WIDTH, y * Tile::TILE_HEIGHT));
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I have a question about `emplace_back` as i've never used it. The `mTiles_` vector is a vector of `Tile`s, not `TileType`s. Is it creating the type of object the `vector` contains and just taking in parameters for the constructor? Or is it actually putting a `TileType` in the vector?

Comment: You may look at [emplace_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/): `Inserts a new element at the end of the vector, right after its current last element. This new element is constructed in place using args as the arguments for its constructor.`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your TileMap constructor calls `.position` which isn't a member of the `Tile` class.

Secondly, @tmlen's answer looks like it works as expected to me. If I run this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Tile
{
public:

    enum TileType {
        TILE_GRASS,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_TOP_LEFT_OUTER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_TOP,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_TOP_RIGHT_OUTER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_LEFT,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_RIGHT,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_RIGHT_INNER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_LEFT_INNER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_LEFT_OUTER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_TOP_RIGHT_INNER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_TOP_LEFT_INNER,
        TILE_OUTSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_RIGHT_OUTER,
        TILE_WALL,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_TOP_LEFT_INNER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_TOP,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_TOP_RIGHT_INNER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_LEFT,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_RIGHT,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_RIGHT_OUTER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_LEFT_OUTER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_LEFT_INNER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_TOP_RIGHT_OUTER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_TOP_LEFT_OUTER,
        TILE_INSIDE_WALL_BOTTOM_RIGHT_INNER,
        TILE_FLOOR
    };

    Tile(TileType t):
        tileType(t)
    {
        cout << "Constructing tile\n";
    }

    virtual ~Tile()
    {
        cout << "Destructing tile\n";
    }


    TileType tileType;

    static int TILE_WIDTH;
    static int TILE_HEIGHT;

    int x;
    int y;

    // pathfinding
    std::shared_ptr<Tile> previousTile;
    float g; // cost to tile (total cost from previous tiles + cost to this tile)
    float h; // cost to next tile
    float f; // g + h
    bool walkable;
};

class TileMap
{
    int mWidth_;
    std::vector<Tile> mTiles_;

    public:
        TileMap(const std::vector<int>& pTiles, int pWidth) : mWidth_(pWidth)
        {
            mTiles_.reserve(pTiles.size());
            for (int i = 0; i != pTiles.size(); ++i)
            {
                const int x = i % mWidth_;
                const int y = i / mWidth_;
                mTiles_.emplace_back(static_cast<Tile::TileType>(pTiles[i]));
                Tile& tile = mTiles_.back();
                tile.x = x;
                tile.y = y;
                //tile.position(sf::Vector2f(x * Tile::TILE_WIDTH, y * Tile::TILE_HEIGHT));
            }
        }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> tiles;
    tiles.push_back(Tile::TileType::TILE_GRASS);
    cout << "Creating tilemap\n";
    TileMap t(tiles, tiles.size());
    cout << "Tilemap created\n";
    cout << "Exiting\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following result:

```
Creating tilemap
Constructing tile
Tilemap created
Exiting
Destructing tile
```

Comment: position is part of the base classes of Tile